# VSTO- word taskpane share in multiple document with value issue

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

i am create a addin using VSTO with c#,

i have create a user control for task-pane, where i have following controls:
1) a text-box- for word document folder,
2) a button - for browsing throw specified folder in the text box,
3) a tree view control to display all the files and folder on the specified path in the text-box,

these are working fine. when i select a document from tree-view it open without the task pane.

i have written the following code for document select.

```
private void treeFiles_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string fullPath = e.Node.Name;
        string checkExt = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
        if (checkExt.Contains("doc"))
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fullPath);
            object fileName = fullPath;
            object readOnly = false;
            object isVisible = true;
            // Here is the way to handle parameters you don't care about in .NET
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            // Make word visible, so you can see what's happening         
            Globals.MainPage.Application.Visible = true;

            Word.Document aDoc = Globals.MainPage.Application.Documents.Open(ref fileName, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref isVisible);

            // Activate the document so it shows up in front
            aDoc.Activate();
        }
    }
```

in the main file i have written the following code:

```
    HomeControl objHomeControl;

    public static Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane taskPaneValue;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        objHomeControl = new HomeControl();
        taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(objHomeControl, "File task pane");
        taskPaneValue.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
        taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
        taskPaneValue.Visible = true;
        this.Application.DocumentOpen += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(Application_DocumentOpen);

    }

    void Application_DocumentOpen(Word.Document Doc)
    {
        HomeControl objHomeControl1 = new HomeControl();
        taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(objHomeControl1, "File task pane",Doc.ActiveWindow);
        taskPaneValue.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
        taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
        taskPaneValue.Visible = true;
    }

    void taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.MyRibbon.tgleButton.Checked = taskPaneValue.Visible;

    }

    public Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane TaskPane
    {
        get
        {
            return taskPaneValue;
        }
    }
```

when i double click on the node, document open  but it add in(UserControl) reinitialized. all the values get reset, add in on/off from ribbon does not work. how can i make a single copy of the UserControl share across all the document.

i have also tried this

```
    void Application_DocumentOpen(Word.Document Doc)
    {
        taskPaneValue = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(objHomeControl, "File task pane",Doc.ActiveWindow);
        taskPaneValue.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionLeft;
        taskPaneValue.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(taskPaneValue_VisibleChanged);
        taskPaneValue.Visible = true;
    }
```

it open the taskpane in the new document. but does not allow me click anywhere. if i click on the parent document, i get the following an exception message:

"COM object that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used."

Help me out.

Comment: I have resolve it.
 [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864][1]
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc338012.aspx][2]



Thank you microsoft team.


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864
  [2]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc338012.aspx

Comment: You should post how you resolved it as an answer and mark it accepted.

Comment: Especially since the first two links you listed are already dead.